# Updating a column causes database error

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, select, sql-update

I'm trying to replace email addresses with a development email address so I can test my email-sending functions.

The function below causes my webpage to stop responding and when I try to look at the tables in SQL Server Management 2008, I'm unable to. I believe the issue is with the line

```
$scrub = sqlsrv_query($conn, "UPDATE " . $tName . " SET DCAEmail='test@test.edu'");
```

I'm not sure, however. The entire function:

```
function scrubEmail($conn){
   $tableNameList = array();
   $getTableName = sqlsrv_query($conn, "Select Name FROM sys.tables");
   while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getTableName)){
      if($row['Name'] !== "sysdiagrams"){
        $tableNameList[] .= $row['Name'];   
      } 
    }

    foreach($tableNameList as &$tName){
        $hasDCAEmail = sqlsrv_query($conn,  "SELECT DCAEmail from " . $tName  );
        if($hasDCAEmail){
            $scrub = sqlsrv_query($conn, "UPDATE " . $tName . " SET DCAEmail='test@test.com'");
            if(!$scrub){
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how many records are you updating?

Comment: why are you unable to look at the tables in SQL SM 2008?

Comment: Uh, do you really want to update the whole table without a where clause?

Comment: Chris - I'm updating roughly 1000 records. 

Raidenance - I don't know :) I try to refresh the database, and expand the 'tables' folder. It gives me a lock error (1222)

Comment: If you want all e-mail addresses to be the same, a simpler answer is to drop that column and store that value once, somewhere else.

Comment: Aaron: Yes, I want to update all the 'real-life' emails to a test email address. this preserves privacy and allows me to receive emails on a test account rather than spamming customers

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to help from Raidenance! The full code is below. I needed to commit the sql_srv queries before doing new ones.

```
function scrubEmail($conn){
   $tableNameList = array();
   $getTableName = sqlsrv_query($conn, "Select Name FROM sys.tables");
   while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getTableName)){
        if($row['Name'] !== "sysdiagrams"){
            $tableNameList[] .= $row['Name'];   
        }
   }

    foreach($tableNameList as &$tabName){
        if ( sqlsrv_begin_transaction( $conn ) === false ) {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));
        }
        $hasFIELD = sqlsrv_query($conn,  "SELECT COLUMNNAME from " . $tabName  );
        if($hasFIELD){
        }
        else {
            sqlsrv_rollback( $conn );
            echo "hasFIELD Transaction rolled back.<br />";
        }

        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($hasDCAEmail)){
            $scrub = sqlsrv_query($conn, "UPDATE " . $tabName . " SET COLUMN='test@test.edu'");
            if($scrub){     
                sqlsrv_commit( $conn );
                echo "Transaction committed.<br />";
            }
            else {
                sqlsrv_rollback( $conn );
                echo "Transaction rolled back.<br />";
            }           
        }
    } 
 }
```